# Change hidden field value using jquery before submitting

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

I am working on a form where there is a hidden input field for button clicked, originally, the value is this field is an empty string. I want to be able to pass in a value to the hidden field as soon as a button is clicked(so I can know the button that was clicked) before the ajax call starts. Right now, this is what I've tried but the userType field still comes back empty after the ajax call is completed. Here's my HTML code.

```
<form role="form"
  id="UserReg"
  name="UserReg"
  >
  
  
<input type="hidden"
       name="user_type_id"
       id="input_userType"
       value="">
       
    <button id="user1" name="user1"> User 1 </button>
    
    <button id="user2" name="user2"> User 2 </button>
```

Here's my jQuery code

```
$("#user1").on('click', function (e)
{   

    //I'm trying to assign 3 to the value of the hidden field before the AJAX call

    $("#input_userType").val("3")

    
    e.preventDefault();

    let Form         =  $('#UserReg');
    



        $.ajax({

            url         :   window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + '/secure/register',
            type        :   'POST',
            contentType :   "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8",
            cache       :   false,
            processData :   true,
            data        :   Form.serialize()
            success     :   function (returnedData)
            {
                consoleLog('returnedData');
                             
                if(jsonData.status === false)
                {
                    // Display Error Message

                }
                else
                {
                   //Do something
                }
            },
            error       :   function (returnedData)
            {
                  //Do something
            }
        });
    }
});
```

After the AJAX call, the value of the hidden field still returns an empty string.

Comment: `$("#input_userType").val(3)` <= you're using jQuery, which does not directly expose the `value` property.  Use the setter `val(<value>)` version

Comment: You need to `EventObject.preventDefault()` on`submit` of the form or else you page will reload, as well.

Comment: Yea, I've also tried that, I still got the same thing. The value doesn't append to the AJAX call.

Answer (score 0):

When modifying the value, you should use the `val` method.

```
memberTypeId.val("3");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#input_userType").val("3");
```

or

```
let memberTypeId = $("#input_userType");
memberTypeId.val("3");
```

https://api.jquery.com/val/

Answer (score 0):

$("#input_userType").val("3")

Answer (score 0):

i dont know if this could be the cause of the error though,but this is what i Observed from the code you posted

```
$("#user1").on('click', function (e)

{   

//I'm trying to assign 3 to the value of the hidden field before the AJAX call

$("#input_userType").val("3")


e.preventDefault();

let Form  =  $('#UserReg');


    $.ajax({

        url         :   window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + '/secure/register',
        type        :   'POST',
        contentType :   "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8",
        cache       :   false,
        processData :   true,
        data        :   Form.serialize() // there should be a comma here also
        success     :   function (returnedData)
        {
            consoleLog('returnedData');
                         
            if(jsonData.status === false)
            {
                // Display Error Message

            }
            else
            {
               //Do something
            }
        },
        error       :   function (returnedData)
        {
              //Do something
        }
    });
// this "}" is an excess  one, as i cant locate the beginning. so it either you remove this 
}
});// or this one
```

So i would suggest you look through your code and adjust appropriately. then we can pick it up from there.